# How to declare a type which selects a single overload of a method?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a class with a public method which has overloads (*simplified example*):

```js
class Foo {
    public flip(str: string): number;
    public flip(num: number): string;
    public flip(num: number, asInt: boolean): string;
    flip(arg: string | number, asInt?: boolean): string | number {
        if (typeof arg === "string") { return arg.length; }
        if (!!asInt) { return Math.trunc(arg).toString(); }
        return arg.toString();
    }
}
```

When used, it is very clear on how it works:

```js
const foo = new Foo();
const num = foo.flip("foo");
//              ^? (method) Foo.flip(str: string): number (+2 overloads)
const str1 = foo.flip(110.5);
//               ^? (method) Foo.flip(num: number): string (+2 overloads)
const str2 = foo.flip(110.5, true);
//               ^? (method) Foo.flip(num: number, asInt: boolean): string (+2 overloads)
```

Declaring a type for all overloads of the method is simple enough:

```js
type Flip = Foo["flip"];
//    ^? type Flip = {␊(str: string): number;␊(num: number): string;␊(num: number, asInt: boolean): string;␊}
```

But how would I declare a type that selects the specific `string->number` overload?

```js
type FlipStringToNum = ??? // how to get this signature: `flip(str: string): number;` ?
```

So I can use it in something *like* this:

```js
declare function executeMethod(method: FlipStringToNum): ReturnType<FlipStringToNum>;
```

*Note*: `Foo` is in a 3rd party library, so I have no control over it. Furthermore, please ignore the implementation of `Foo` as it is just for the sake of demonstrating the issue at hand.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoAcCuARiAJbDQBmJOAFBAC4BOAXNPQ8QHYDmAlCx3gC2BAKYMA3Bmy5CJMpWI0Bg-kNEM%20rRpy6TM2fEVIUq1ZauFiANNEgBJDnRYFEIEWA6a2OvdIU0wBi4Wb25oAB9oZXUbe0cAfmdXd08Q7TDI6LEUKWlsYnJoajoATxwReELArmgAXnroACJQrkaeFGgGETo8Bg5bIIA6N246AAtxaABfXLzoAqKAQkW4unbkTu7e-oBZMHHBxjwOYGpqnkP4AGV0rmoeSZn9Oa6evoGuS5v2bnvfbCeTwwwHgHHoFEQdSiIgA7nBEH9gaDwcooeREIN-NRGuj4G09AB6AlzEnQAB68SRYLoWgYAEY0RisXS6QAGQYAVgeGCJpJJFKp4LYACZGfBMaYWeyOTYjiJueheXy8gL0BhSuU4FQoQh4ABtHFURoAXUJxOwqvVZREWsU3x0ABV4AA5IRQ%20Ie6C8sbwOF0JBcbrQcbEGAQYhcDj7XoiFgAAyxbDSP14FnU4jj0EpavQABMRKBAjbyMdgHRiKDoCIAB4FvB0EQ7bo%203PUQTN%20C5liwKj27hO12CTQAJS2fQd1oAPD27bcB0IAHziIA)

Answer (score 0):

> Note: This answer was written in response to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73229682/1). Afterward, a new, significant constraint [was edited into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73229682/2): the code in question cannot be changed by the author.

AFAIK, TypeScript doesn't currently (v`4.7.4`) offer a way to *derive* specific overload signatures. It's kind of a one-way encoding into the AST, so if you need the individual signature types for other things (and want to avoid potential type fragmentation caused by declaring them again apart from the overloaded function declaration), then you'll have to define them individually and then apply them.

One way to do that is to use an asserted overloaded function expression, as demonstrated below. If your implementation is entirely incompatible with the asserted function type, you'll still get a compiler diagnostic error just like in other incompatible assertion cases.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=16&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgSzAZWAJygXigCgM7oBcUBaCAdgOYCUWAfFOQK4C2ARhGgNwBQoksRGAByrLLmYtikjmlqYGpCpV79o8JAElywcTknTWsgDRQAhnm3BibAPa24EM+XmL0y3jwD0XqABUAC2hbADdOOFszABMIKKgAM3IoNT5wdSEYJOwNFHQoADJBJFEWAqKwK08fKE0oW3I4ECgKBGAEM0QAL1jkgIQ8BKZyAGM2+rqmYDwEGN7oYbgLAeBbKAhyPCY0aGAAs2BvXzNGCAB3QZGxpP7GW11h7f2e+NsMCDC0JoWl5o3gZ2GEEOuCcwwCvwIAIgAHIBgAieJCOFQFgQXa2OKnBBwOBQbbxTjJVa7G62NgAKwgo2oADoeMN6gQEkI9DgzGhKMQlFQoAAfRhGTimCxWAD8Nnsjmc1C57h5-JkhIUUAA3jwoM14rg1LYtezKFhMNhYXLKNDaCq8Witkl9TTHFRdlwoABfdWa3AAQk9Ip0FqtwBtUAAsvsAjT0ENhmyObSVqgyFQcNRnW6NdtA2hbRyI7YE8pk7wXbQLOVMrxqgA9as1mtQACCeDwnF0rSgQW2PHpiybsHsqqgYCYbEQw2ZSHEiKQqa7DL+CX72HIZz7tkLPBethpU7AOGhAEYAEwAZnNvA1Pkroo39m3QhwR+PKfdl+vm7vSAfJ5pABYAKwAGymJGEDPheXhXjeW47l+x6-oBpjxB0zZgVAr48EAA)

```ts
type FlipStr = (str: string) => number;
type FlipNum = (num: number) => string;
type FlipInt = (num: number, asInt: boolean) => string;

// The overloaded fn type
type FlipFn = FlipStr & FlipNum & FlipInt;

// I only initialized this function outside the class to ensure that
// a new function is not created for every class instance
// (each instance's "flip" method will refer to this object).
const flip = ((arg: string | number, asInt?: boolean): string | number => {
  if (typeof arg === 'string') { return arg.length; }
  if (!!asInt) { return Math.trunc(arg).toString(); }
  return arg.toString();
}) as FlipFn;
// ^^^^^^^^^ Assert it here

class Foo { public flip = flip; }

const foo = new Foo();
foo.flip('123');
  //^? (property) Foo.flip: (str: string) => number (+2 overloads)
foo.flip(123);
  //^? (property) Foo.flip: (num: number) => string (+2 overloads)
foo.flip(123.456, true);
  //^? (property) Foo.flip: (num: number, asInt: boolean) => string (+2 overloads)
foo.flip(123.456, false);
  //^? (property) Foo.flip: (num: number, asInt: boolean) => string (+2 overloads)
```

> Aside: because your method doesn't use any state from the class instance (it's actually [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)), you might consider making it [static](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#static-members).

Comment: thank you! definitely a workaround, but unfortunately, I only used the example above as an MVP simplification and the plot thickens by the fact that Foo actually is part of a 3rd party package, so this workaround will probably not do the trick.

Comment: @DoronG I see... that's why it's always important to include in your question a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which is actually representative of the details in your scenario.